# How to lock multiple activities to portrait?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 different activities and I want my app to be portrait only, how can I ensure all stay portrait?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Android Manifest File

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Do it for each activity like

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Needless to tell that it usually a bad experience to lock your app in portrait only. Think twice before do it, maybe layout with Landscape qualifier will be a better decision